# Oracle merging column is giving error

Tags: sql, oracle, column-alias

I have 2 columns in oracle, that I am merging like below

```
select SURVEY_AREA_7_12 || ' ' || HISSA_NO_7_12 
from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_FARMING_MST
```

which is working fine. But when I add my own name to the columns like below

```
select SURVEY_AREA_7_12 || ' ' || HISSA_NO_7_12 as 712_Column 
from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_FARMING_MST
```

it gives error as

> ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`712_Column` is an invalid SQL identifier. You can't start an identifier with a number. If you need this, you need to quote the name:

```
select SURVEY_AREA_7_12 || ' ' || HISSA_NO_7_12 as "712_Column"
from XXCUS.XXACL_PN_FARMING_MST
```

Comment: can't I use single `'` quote ?

Comment: @nad: No. Single quotes are for string constants in SQL. Double quotes are for identifiers. See the chapter "Basic Elements of Oracle SQL" in the manual for details: [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements003.htm#SQLRF00217) and [here](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/sql_elements008.htm#SQLRF00223)

Comment: while adding this in my c# code, like below `OracleDataAdapter da712 = new OracleDataAdapter("SELECT (survey_area_7_12 || ' ' || hissa_no_7_12) AS "712_Column" FROM xxcus.xxacl_pn_farming_mst", ObjPriCon);` I am getting error as **) expected**

Comment: @nad: that has nothing to do with SQL. You are nesting double quotes inside a string literal with double quotes. Please refer to the C# language specification on how to do that.

Comment: @nad - do you really have to call the column `712_Column`? (Do you care about upper case and lower case, in addition to the digits first?) In general it is MUCH MUCH better if you get in the habit of using "standard" identifiers. Why doesn't `column_712` (which will be written in the catalog and in output of your queries in upper case, `COLUMN_712`) work for you?

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your alias has a number in first position; you can quote it or change the alias:

```
Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production
SQL> select 'a' as 1ABC from dual;
select 'a' as 1ABC from dual
              *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00923: FROM keyword not found where expected


SQL> select 'a' as "1ABC" from dual;

1ABC
----
a
```

A number in a position different from the first gives no problem:

```
SQL> select 'a' as ABC1 from dual;

ABC1
----
a
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the identifier with double quotes `"`

```
SELECT (SURVEY_AREA_7_12 || ' ' || HISSA_NO_7_12) AS "712_Column"
FROM XXCUS.XXACL_PN_FARMING_MST
```

Comment: can't I use single quote `'` ?

Comment: @nad: Single quotes refers a character value, like what you used in the select for adding a space `' '`

Answer (score 2):

you are using alias name starts with number. That is the problem. Please use column_712 and execute...